# How can configure a Sveltekit project to target node.js 14?

Tags: node.js, babeljs, svelte, sveltekit

I already have a svelte kit project which I build using node.js 18 and 20, but someone I'm developing it for wants me to host it on Namecheap's shared hosting server which only support node.js 14.21.2

I tried to use babel (poorly because I'm not used to it) but it didn't work.
After several hours I decided to ask for help here, PLEASE HELP!

The error I get running the output build with node.js 14:

```
failed to load config from /home/valentin/coding/projects/batteries_project/vite.config.ts
error during build:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:149:18)
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I think some other things might fail, even if I fixed this, so help if you can.